# Opencart payment wont work, -9 simulation forbidden

Tags: php, opencart

I am running a version of opencart, and added a payment module. This module wont work because of the: -9 simulation forbidden. I cant find it on google so I was hoping someone here would know the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: _a version of opencart_ : Which version?

_a payment module_ : Which payment module? Is it Sisow?

Comment: Sisow ideal. Opencart 1.5.4. Someone told me once it was a server setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it has something to do with the settings in your Sisow account. To make test transactions you have to allow this in your account first.

From the Sisow FAQ: https://www.sisow.nl/epay-online-betaalmogelijkheden/epay-veel-gestelde-vragen

> **Wat betekent “Simulation forbidden”?**
>
> De foutmelding “simulation forbidden” betekent dat u in uw webshop
>   heeft aangegeven dat u wilt testen maar dit niet heeft aangegeven in
>   het account van Sisow. Om testtransacties uit te voeren, moet u de
>   optie ‘Testen met behulp van simulator toestaan’ inschakelen. Deze
>   vindt u onder 'Mijn profiel' op het tabblad 'Geavanceerd'.
>
> Wilt u de webshop meteen in de live modus hebben, dan moet u de
>   testmodus in uw webshop-omgeving uitschakelen. Vergeet niet na het
>   testen niet om beide testmodes uit te schakelen wanneer u klaar bent
>   met testen.

Comment: You just made my Christmas come early! I have been looking in all te wrong places for weeks! Thanks you! It worked!